# Assign Default Request Data in Model Schema in ASP.NET Core SwaggerUI using "Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta901

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using "Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta901" for my asp.net core application.

I want to programmatically add a default value for my model schema when they click the model schema to set value in swagger UI.

I have seen couple of post related to this, however I could not find it working.Could anyone please help me with a simple example ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by writing custom implementation of IOperationFilter.  Please find the detailed article with code sample [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/69)